# Action based redirect ASP.Net Core Razor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages, html-input

Synopsis of the place I am at:
In my program on page 1 they select a printer and click a button which submits a service call and loads the next page, machine information. The redirect action calls the following method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSelectThisPrinter(int? printerID)
    {
        var printerServiceCall = new Service_Calls
        {
            PrinterID = (int)printerID,
            Time = DateTime.Now,
            Date = DateTime.Now               
        };
        _context.Service_Calls.Add(printerServiceCall);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        var ServiceCalls = from m in _context.Service_Calls
                           select m;
        Service_Calls ServiceCall = ServiceCalls.Last();            
        return RedirectToPage("MachineInformaion?id=" + ServiceCall.ID);
        //return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

In this code the printerID = 1 is a placeholder until I work out how to pass in a specific machines details (any help on passing through that would be helpful). 
The HTML for this page, with the buttons, is as follows:

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>

                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].MachineID)
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.LogSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].Log_ID)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.LeaseSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].Lease_ID)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.SerialSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].Serial_Number)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.SolutionSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].Solution)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.AdditionalSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].Additional_Info)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.InstallationSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].InstallationDate)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.MonoClickSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].Mono_Click)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.ColourCLickSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].Colour_Click)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.MinimumSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].Minimum)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.PartsSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].Parts_Warranty)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.ITSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].IT_Support)</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./SelectPrinter" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.ContractSortParam">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printer[0].Contract_Type)</a>
            </th>
            <th>Select Printer</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

@foreach (var item in Model.Printer) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MachineID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Log_ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Lease_ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Serial_Number)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Solution)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Additional_Info)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InstallationDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mono_Click)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Colour_Click)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Minimum)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Parts_Warranty)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IT_Support)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contract_Type)
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="get" asp-page-handler="OnGetSelectThisPrinter" asp-route-id="@item.MachineID">
                    <button value="Select Printer" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, at the moment the buttons don't do anything. It looks like they aren't going into the OnGetSelectThisPrinter Method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can use `<a>` tag to access the handler, since you only need to pass a parameter.

```
<a asp-page="/Printer" asp-page-handler="SelectThisPrinter" asp-route-printerID="@item.MachineID">SelectThisPrinter</a>
```

Handler in Printer page:

```
public IActionResult OnGetSelectThisPrinter(int printerID)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This worked really well thanks. It redirects as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To start, this tutorial gives a much more in depth discussion of the answer I'm about to give. Check it out: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

Hi there! Let's start with making the button work. In order to redirect the user to a particular action of the page, we can use the `asp-page-handler` attribute to specify the method that handles the request. Additionally, we use the `asp-route-id` attribute to describe which printer we have selected. Finally, we wrap this all up in a form. So, we replace

```
<input type="button" onclick="SelectThisPrinter()" value="Select Printer" />
```

with

```
<form method="get" asp-page-handler="selectThisPrinter" asp-route-id="@item.MachineID">
  <button value="Select Printer" />
</form>
```

Then, in your code-behind, we can perform some simple changes to your handler. We change

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> SelectThisPrinter()
{
  int printerID = 1;
  ...
}
```

to

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetSelectThisPrinter(int? printerId)
{
  ...
}
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any further questions.